# How can I solve this error?: Scss compiler error: Error: File to import: ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions not found in file: undefined

Tags: node.js, sass, bootstrap-5

When I look in the `scss` folder, I don't find a `functions` folder.

I don't know what to try other than `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

IDK exactly what is the context of what you're trying to achieve. But `./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions` is not a directory but rather a reference to the `_functions.scss` file in `./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/`.

Comment: Thank you. That might point me in the right direction.